# Adding a Postgresql role to a database after the RDS instance was created via Terraform

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to add a role to a Postgresql database after creating it in RDS via Terraform.

I have two separate modules, one creating the RDS instance, one adding the new role to it. The database address is an output of the `persistence` module and an input of the `persistenceApplicationRole` module. The problem seems to be that the Postgresql provider is ran before the RDS instance is created, so the address is empty.
The error I am getting is:

```
Error: Error initializing PostgreSQL client: error detecting capabilities: error PostgreSQL version: dial tcp :5432: connect: connection refused

  on ../modules/persistenceApplicationRole/main.tf line 9, in provider "postgresql":
   9: provider postgresql {
```

Running the modules separately via the `-target=module.persistence` flag works, since `persistenceApplicationRole` picks up the database address once it is created. 
I have found an example with this exact scenario for the MySQL Provider in their documentation [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/mysql/index.html).

```
# module.persistenceApplicationRole
provider postgresql {
  host      = var.databaseAddress
  username  = data.external.root_credentials.result["username"]
  password  = data.external.root_credentials.result["password"]
  superuser = false
}

resource "postgresql_role" "application_role" {
  name     = data.external.application_credentials.result["username"]
  password = data.external.application_credentials.result["password"]

  login               = true
  encrypted_password  = true
  skip_reassign_owned = true
  skip_drop_role      = true
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [1.4.0 release of the Postgresql provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-postgresql/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#140-december-25-2019) added `expected_version` which you can use to avoid the feature detection at plan time that attempts to connect to the database. This was introduced in the [0.1.1 release](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-postgresql/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#011-january-19-2018) a while back and broke people being able to create the underlying instance and configure the database at the same time.

To use the `expected_version` you would do something like this:

```
provider postgresql {
  host      = var.databaseAddress
  username  = data.external.root_credentials.result["username"]
  password  = data.external.root_credentials.result["password"]
  superuser = false

  expected_version = "10.1"
}
```

The more common use case would be creating an RDS instance or something else and interpolating that across:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "database" {
  # ...
}

provider "postgresql" {
  version = ">=1.4.0"

  host             = aws_db_instance.database.address
  port             = aws_db_instance.database.port
  username         = aws_db_instance.database.user
  password         = aws_db_instance.database.password
  sslmode          = "require"
  connect_timeout  = 15
  superuser        = false
  expected_version = aws_db_instance.database.engine_version
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the `expected_version` field did indeed solve my issue.

Comment: In "the more common use case" - is that expected to work feeding in `engine_version` from the `aws_db_instance` resource? Because it's not for me; I get `Error: dial tcp [::1]:0: connect: can't assign requested address`

Comment: @JonBurgess I'm not currently using the Postgresql provider at my new role but if you could ask a new question with what you've tried and the versions of Terraform and the plugins you are using and link back to this answer then I'm sure someone will be able to help.